# Pass an object to a class constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I have two classes: poly and Node. I create a linked list of Nodes, then I want to create a new poly object that contains a pointer to my first Node object.

Here is the calling code:

```
poly *polyObj = new poly(head);
```

I have tested my code and confirmed that "head" contains the linked list of nodes, also head is declared as a Node *.

Here are the class definitions:

```
class poly
{
  private:
    Node *start;  
  public:
    poly(Node *head)
    {
      start = head;
    }
};

class Node
{
   private:
    double coeff;
    int exponent;
    Node *next;

  public:
    Node(double c, int e, Node *nodeobjectPtr)
    {
      coeff = c;
      exponent = e;
      next = nodeobjectPtr;
    }
};
```

I don't understand why I can't pass a Node * to my poly constructor.

Comment: The calling code should probably just be `poly polyObj(head);`

Comment: So what was the error exactly?

Comment: You haven't explained what *specifically* you're trying to accomplish that's not working. What results are you getting and how do they differ from the desired results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand why I can't pass a Node * to my poly constructor!!

Because `poly` needs to know that `Node` is a type. You can achieve that via a forward declaration:

```
class Node; // fwd declaration

class poly
{
private:
    Node *start;    
public:
  poly(Node *head)
  {
    start = head;
  }
};
```

Alternatively, you can place the `Node` class definition before `poly`'s definition.