# Using an object of a parent class within a child class. Do you need to pass the object as a class constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

It is likely that this is a duplicate question, but I haven't been able to find the best way to approach this problem.

I have a parent class, which creates an object, which has useful methods operating on that object. I then want to create a child class, which takes the object of the parent class by reference and has a bunch of other methods which operate on it.

I was wondering how best to approach this? Should I pass a pointer to an object of the parent class as the constructor of the child class?

What I would like to do :

```
class obj_parent{
    initializes object
    virtual void method_1
    virtual void method_2
}

class operation: public obj_parent {
    void opertation_method_1(*object)
    void opertation_method_2(object)
}
```

Also what difference would it make if the parent class and the child class were templated?

Some references on the subject which I didn't find fully answered my question, but could be useful.
[Pass an object to a class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183523/pass-an-object-to-a-class-constructor)
[Passing object of a template class to constructor of another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239871/passing-object-of-a-template-class-to-constructor-of-another-class)

Comment: Your wording is misleading and unclear.   All that is necessary to call an accessible member function of an `obj_parent` is a pointer or reference to an an instance of `object_parent`  (and any arguments needed).   It doesn't matter how `operations` gets such a pointer or reference - but it needs to.   If the member functions are inaccessible, there is no way (because that is the purpose in making a member function inaccessible).

Comment: Is the object private or protected (or public) in the parent class?

Comment: Try asking from a different direction. What are you trying to do? What do you want your calling code to look like? That might suggest the best ways to solve your problems

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I was trying to keep the topic general to avoid downvotes and I'm a relative beginner with polymorphism/inheritance. I've created a matrix class and then have a child class which is solvers. It should take two matrix objects and solve the systems of equations. There are some methods in the matrix class which are useful such as print_matrix, so I want to keep the solver class as a child of matrix. But Im just unsure as to how to go about using a matrix in the solver class without having to reinitialise a matrix when you create a instance of the solver class.

Comment: The object is public in the parent class

Comment: I think it is XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the example below does exactly what you wanted to do: the child modifies an instance of a parent object through a reference. The parent holds a single int. Yes, in real life an object usually would have more than one member variable, but this is just an illustrative example.

```
class parentInt {
public:
    int memberNumber;
    parentInt(int number) {
        memberNumber = number;
    }
    parentInt() {
        memberNumber = 0;
    }
};

class childInt : public parentInt {
public:
    parentInt& mReferenceToParentObject;
    childInt(parentInt& referenceToParentObject) :mReferenceToParentObject(referenceToParentObject) {}
    void addOne() {
        mReferenceToParentObject.memberNumber++;
    }
    void subtractOne() {
        mReferenceToParentObject.memberNumber--;
    }
};


int main()
{
    parentInt p(5); //parent int is 5
    childInt c(p); //child int is a reference to parent
    c.addOne();  // parent's memberNumber is now 6 because the child modified the parent through the reference
    c.subtractOne();  // parent's memberNumber is now 5 because the child modified the parent through the reference
}
```

If your doing this to solve a system of equations (not mentioned in the original question, see comments), replace memberNumber above with a vector of vectors to represent a 2D matrix and then change addOne to an algorithm like Gaussian Elimination to solve the system of equations.